# anchor tags jump to avoid fixed header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed header of 97px. I also have anchor tags set up that jump to each section of the page. The way my webpage is set out the anchor tags jump to the correct places by the titles of the pages are hidden behind the fixed header.

For this to work the way i want it to the anchor tags need to jump -97px from where they are currenlty jumping too?

How can i achieve this.

Comment: Fiddle please, I believe it can be fixed with some padding

Comment: You'll either need padding on the things you're jumping to, or you'll have to use javascript to offset your jump.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've done this in the past similar to what @kthornbloom suggested, with something like this on the anchor :

```
position: relative;
top: -97px;
```

I'm not 100% on how kosher using a negative number for `top` is though.

Comment: That’s perfectly “kosher”, all four position “attributes” (top, left, right, bottom) can take negative length values, no problem.

Comment: If this is my anchor link how would i add that? <a href="#contact">Contact</a> <a id="contact"></a>